# qt.webChannelTransport undefined in QWebEngineView

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qtwebengine

I ran into a problem using QWebChannel for accessing an object from JavaScript. I'm currently using Qt5.4.2.

Here's my CPP code :

```
myObject::myObject(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
{

    QWebEngineView* m_pView = new QWebEngineView(this);

    QWebChannel channel;
    channel.registerObject(QString("myObject"), this);

    m_pView->load(QUrl("file:///D:/index.html"));

    setCentralWidget(m_pView);

}
```

In my index.html, I am including `qwebchannel.js` :

`<script type="text/javascript" src="qrc:///qtwebchannel/qwebchannel.js"></script>`

And in my javascript file, I am trying to retrieve my object like this :

```
new QWebChannel(qt.webChannelTransport, function(channel) {

var myObject = channel.objects.myObject;

});
```

However, I get the following error in the console :

`Error: qt is not defined`

I also tried to replace it with `navigator.qtWebChannelTransport` but I got :

`Error: transport is not defined`

Can somebody tell me what did I do wrong? Thanks.

**Edit** : Is qt.webChannelTransport only accessible with Qt5.5? It seems to be the case when I read the doc of `QWebEnginePage::setWebChannel`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats correct.

`QWebChannel` integration with `QWebEngine` is only available from version 5.5 as stated [here](http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/development/2014-August/018196.html) by Milian, the main developer of the module.

Answer (score 4):

You must setWebChannel before load url

Comment: This isn't a really good answer.  Add more information or an example.  This is more of a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You have to google `qwebchannel.js` to get the default code (it's a lot of code actually) or get it from out of Qt's directories somehow.  I put mine under `<qrc>/qtwebchannel/qwebchannel.js`.  Then make sure you import it as a regular javascript into your index.html but with source as "qrc:/qtwebchannel/qwebchannel.js".  I had your exact error earlier today, and something I did fixed it - was probably including that script.

Answer (score 0):

For others having the same issue but using Qt 5.5+, make sure you have `QT += webchannel` in your `.pro` file.